# Is it possible to call shmget() in two thread inside one process ?

Tags: c, multithreading, shared-memory

I have one process which has two thread main thread and event thread ,can i use shared memory between two different thread in a single process for sending the data from one thread to Other ?

If I am using shmget() in two different thread in same process ,one shmget() get the shmid and other  return with -1 and failed  ,so need to know either its a valid scenario or not ?

Comment: Why do you need to use shmget()? All memory is already shared between threads.

Comment: you can use normal malloc as a global variable where the thread can access it normally but their memory is already share and the thread can access it directly unlike process where you need to use shmget or use pipe to send data between each other